# Backup only orders, products, customers

Tags: magento-1.9, database, backup

I want to backup and restore only important data from database.

Do you which tables are must have or any other idea how to restore?

Thank you

Comment: What is "important"? The store only consists of orders, (creditmemo, quotes, shipping data), products (attributes, configurable connectisons, images, ...) and customers with their click pathes, voting, etc.

Answer (score 1):

## Back up the entire thing.

Not to be flippant, but if you don't already know which tables are important *then they all are*.

Comment: This cannot be emphasized enough. If you don't know what you're doing, don't mess around with individual tables.

Answer (score 0):

this is really not a good idea to split the database backup. It really doesnt take very long to dump the database. If your concerned, what about running a mysql master and slave database, and then dumping the slave database.

Also suggest backing up off the server, I use a small script s3cmd which allows me to dump the database and backup to S3 all in one go. It also allows you to keep days/weeks/months of sql backups

brendan

Answer (score 0):

As stated, you shouldn't split up the Magento database. If you've really got your heart set on it, you'll want to spend some time looking at http://www.magereverse.com/ . You will need to be sure that a partial DB backup won't cause issues elsewhere due to constraints. Not an endeavor for the faint of heart.